# Activar un boton desde otra clase en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

tengo dos clases, uno se llama Frame1 y el otro, Frame2. Frame2 tiene un botón que está inhabilitado, lo que quiero es apretar el botón de Frame1 para que me active el botón de la otra clase, ya que mientras no presione el botón 1, el botón 2 no debe estar habilitado por nada del mundo. Quisiera saber cómo es posible lograrlo, porque hasta ahora me sale error.

Este es mi layout del Frame1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este el código del Frame1:

```
public class Frame1 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public Button frame1btn;

public Frame2 f;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_frame1);

    f = new Frame2();

    frame1btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonframe1);
    frame1btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    f.frame2btn.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Este es el layout del Frame2:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código del Frame2:

```
public class Frame2 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public Button frame2btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_frame2);

    frame2btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonframe2);
    frame2btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Lo lograste!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: y al hacer click en el boton1, aparte de activar el botón 2, te lleva a la actividad 2 o sigue en la activiad1?

Comment: Quiero que se mantenga en la actividad1 nomás, y que ya cuando vaya a la actividad2 el botón esté activado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso puede hacerse con Shared Preferences (SP).
En onCreate de la actividad 1:

```
 final SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Preferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 //sharedPref.edit().clear().apply();  // opcional si quieres que inicie como desabilitado el botón cada vez que se cree la activity

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // llamas al editor del SP
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            //colocas una clave (botón) con su valor(activar), luego commit o apply para que se guarde ese valor en SP
            editor.putString("boton", "activar");
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
```

En onCreate de la actividad 2 obtienes el valor del sp:

```
  // llamas a SP:
 SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Preferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  // luego creas un String con el valor que guardastes del key(boton), en caso de
  // que no hayas guardado nada tomara el valor por default, en este caso "nada"
 String clave = sharedPref.getString("boton", "nada");
  // y comparas el resultado para activar o no el botón:
  if("activar".equals(clave)) {
        frame2btn.setEnabled(true);
    }else {
        frame2btn.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudó bastante y pude completarlo! ☺